# select everything inside curly bracket

Tags: regex, powershell

can we just get results as

```
edf560af-db87-11e3-80d2-806e6f6e6963
faadf429-db69-11e3-919f-e0db55bf0b1b
```

Tried

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume |select  deviceid) -replace '\D'
# removes all except numbers
```

here is the cmd

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume |select  deviceid

deviceid                                                                                                                                                                               
--------                                                                                                                                                                               
\\?\Volume{edf560af-db87-11e3-80d2-806e6f6e6963}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{faadf429-db69-11e3-919f-e0db55bf0b1b}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{faadf42d-db69-11e3-919f-e0db55bf0b1b}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{faadf433-db69-11e3-919f-e0db55bf0b1b}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{faadf439-db69-11e3-919f-e0db55bf0b1b}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{edf560b0-db87-11e3-80d2-806e6f6e6963}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{edf560b1-db87-11e3-80d2-806e6f6e6963}\                                                                                                                                      
\\?\Volume{edf560b5-db87-11e3-80d2-806e6f6e6963}\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=(Volume{))([\s\S]| |w\[0-9]| )+?(?=(}))
or simpler
(?<=Volume{).+(?=})
```

https://regex101.com/r/MHnxxh/4
or
https://regex101.com/r/MHnxxh/5

Answer (score 0):

Even a variant of your try can't work because it would also include the `e` in volume:

```
PS> (Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume |select  -expand deviceid) -replace '[^0-9a-f]'
ed0addcdf000000000000100000000000
ed0addcdf000000000000501f00000000
e775fc6ae9c7511e7b58e10604b928269
e2367fe0e45e311e6b548806e6f6e6963
```

Here another working solution using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | Select-String '(?<=\{)[0-9a-f\-]+(?=\})' | ForEach-Object {$_.matches.value}
```

Comment: The first suggestion preserves the `e` from `Volume` (notice how the resulting strings are 33, not 32 chars wide)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to capture only the hex digits between the LEFT CURLY BRACKET and the RIGHT CURLY BRACKET.

```
PS C:\src\t> cat .\dsm.ps1
Get-CimInstance CIM_StorageVolume |
    Select-Object DeviceID |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -match ".*{([-0-9a-fA-F]*)}.*" } |
    ForEach-Object { $matches[1] -replace '-' }
```

The output is:

```
PS C:\src\t> .\dsm.ps1
04ec358ff8bc11e3bac6806e6f6e6963
04ec3590f8bc11e3bac6806e6f6e6963
2bd2c32a00000000000090b4e8000000
c0adb44bbbcc11e5b3e7806e6f6e6963
```